# Pusher or anything to show user listing ordered by their online status?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, pusher

I am building a web-site/mobile-API using Laravel 4.2 PHP framework. Private messaging between users is a key feature there. I was wondering if I can use Pusher to list all the registered users ordered by their online status. where currently logged-in users go to the top and recently logged-off users go next, and so on. Chatting apps like Skout has such user listing and I am trying to make the same sort of thing there.

was taking a long, hard look at Pusher and Firebase. Firebase seems to support the use case out of the box. Whereas I can't really figure out if I can make such user listing with Pusher. Their documentation notes that Pusher's presence channel has max 100 members limit. Whereas the total # of users I'm expecting is well over 20,000 users. I'd like to know if there's any better alternative to Firebase for this.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parse](https://www.parse.com/).  It has the same object oriented data store structure as Firebase.  Personally, I've only used Firebase since it's better known and has more traction.

At one time, Parse was probably much more ahead in terms of the amount of features it gave a developer, but Firebase seemed to have caught up pretty well.  They both have extensive language SDKs, their own authentication features (that developers can plug into), and their pricing schemas are pretty similar.

Comment: Firebase and Parse are pretty unique in terms of features. Firebase focuses on real-time persistence, introducing a new programming paradigm, where Parse takes a more queue/message bussing approach, focused on solving the event messaging queue model.